# Vagrantfile を手で削除してしまった場合のインスタンスの削除方法

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

今使っているプロジェクトの Vagrant を起動しようとすると

```
Vagrant cannot forward the specified ports on this VM, since they
would collide with some other application that is already listening
on these ports. The forwarded port to 3000 is already in use
on the host machine.

To fix this, modify your current projects Vagrantfile to use another
port. Example, where '1234' would be replaced by a unique host port:

  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 1234

Sometimes, Vagrant will attempt to auto-correct this for you. In this
case, Vagrant was unable to. This is usually because the guest machine
is in a state which doesn't allow modifying port forwarding.
```

となってしまうのですが、他のプロジェクトで使用している Vagrantfile は
`vagrant destroy`コマンドではなく、Mac の Finder 上から
ディレクトリ自体を削除してしまったので、他にはない状態です…。

VirtualBox Maneger からも削除して、
`~/VirtualBox\ VMs` の中にある他のプロジェクトのディレクトリも削除して
`vagrant global-status --prune` もしてみましたが、状況は変わらずです。

解決方法を教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: tcpポートが衝突しているようですね。そのポートはなんのプロセスが使用しているか分かりますか？Linuxなら `netstat -anp|grep ポート番号`  で確認してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
`lsof -n -P -i :3000` して、使われているプロセス番号を `kill -9` したら行けました！